# Can't get server to catch Authorization header WP Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, authorization, jwt, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to develop an Android app for a WordPress/WooCommerce website.
I can't seem to catch the Authorization header.
I am using [JWT Auth Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/), I've set up the secret key and cors=true in wp-config.

```
define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'qP>:$YKu7H%6#I&!i.delK^`Ehkm]k~4A*rJ3f<vJj+{ZKgTzRsEt<*PxRxhy;(t');
define('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE', true);
```

I've added every possible line I found on the internet to .htacces, currently I'm only with what the plugin requires, these are placed below "RewriteEngine On" and are at the top and above all others.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

This was the common fix throughout all the people who had this problem.
I tried [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) and it worked with it's customized Authentication header, but it returned "not logged in" when I tried /users/me with the token it gave me.

I've also tried editing class-jwt-auth-public.php file:

```
if (!$auth) {
    $allHeaders = getallheaders();
    $auth = isset($allHeaders['Authorization']) ? 
    $allHeaders['Authorization'] : false;
}
```

I'm using [REST API LOG](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-log/) to analyze the requests and see that the Authorization header is not sent.
Requests were sent with Postman and from my S7 Edge.
I am losing my mind these few days trying to get this to work. Hopefully, you guys can help.